# Controlling the loading of Java class in CLASSPATH

Tags: java, jvm, classpath, jvm-arguments

I am trying to apply patch using classpath approach, I mean I am adding modified class files as jar file, and while classes are getting loaded new version of classes are loaded. Therefore application is patched without changing original jar file.

The following classpath definition works fine;

```
java -cp patch/patch.jar;bin/  com.test.PatchClasspath
```

but when order of lib classes are changed it does not work.(as usual)

```
java -cp bin/;patch/patch.jar  com.test.PatchClasspath
```

I would like to know is there a JVM parameter which indicates the lib loading order?

EDITED:
I amd modifying Util->print() method to verify patch is applied.

```
package com.test;

public class PatchClasspath {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Util util = new Util();
    util.print();
}   

}


package com.test;

public class Util {


public void print(){
    System.out.println("Version-1");
}

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting? The order should not matter.

Comment: There is not an error, the problem with second approach is that since modified classes (patch.jar) is loaded first then original classes are overwrites them all. As a result patch.jar is not loaded.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what `PatchClasspath` does.

Comment: You have to know that the order does matter in class loading, the first class that gets loaded cannot be overwritten by next class. So you have to modify you startup script to manually load your class first before the class from jar is loaded.

Comment: My question is clear, of course I know order is important. I just want to know is there a JVM parameter to change that order. May be new JVM version changes its characteristic of class loading way.

Comment: I don’t understand your question as it answers itself; `-cp` *is* the option controlling the order. Why should there be another one?

Comment: Think about there is an indicator makes classloading starts either from beginning or end. With this way classloding order will be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such parameter indicate the lib loading order in JVM (I believe), however, the java -classpath option itself will determine the class loading order base on the paths you put.

JDK document explain this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html

Specification order

The order in which you specify multiple class path entries is important. The Java interpreter will look for classes in the directories in the order they appear in the class path variable. In the example above, the Java interpreter will first look for a needed class in the directory C:\java\MyClasses. Only if it doesn't find a class with the proper name in that directory will the interpreter look in the C:\java\OtherClasses directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try `-verbose:class`, this will show you all the loaded classes, in which order they were loaded and from which jar they were loaded.

To control the order of classes loaded, you can modify the order of jars in your classpath, using the `java -cp`. I do not think there is a way howto control the order of classes being loaded from a specific jar.

To verify that the patch is applied, a simple/dummy solution is to add a static field with the `System.out.println("")`. For Example:

```
static {
  System.out.println("[DBG] : My Patch v1.0 is loaded.");
}
```

Comment: is there a way to control the which class loaded first which class loaded last? This is what I want to know

Comment: The patched class you want to load simply must be in a placed in a jar that is before the jar containing the original class.

Comment: Thanks for you contribution, you have given valuable information but my exact expectation. However I do understand that there is not way to control the class loading order except changing the order of library in classpath manually.

Comment: but modifying the lib order in the classpath is not difficult at all. I do it every day.

Comment: Sometime using gear manually is most enjoyable than automatic one